# About call() method in Callable interface. When invoked other static method in call(), if it will blocked and impacts performance ?

Tags: java, json, multithreading, static-methods, callable

I created a thread pool by ExecutorService and submited 10 tasks to run, like this:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();  
    ArrayList<Future<String>>  results = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();  
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){  
        results.add(exec.submit(new TaskWithResult(//parameters...)));  
    }
```

And in my class's call() method, I invoked some other Utility class's static method, like this :

```
public String call() throws Exception {
        //invoke tool static method
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONParserUtil.getJson(filePath);
    JSONObject childNode = JSONParserUtil.getChildNode(jsonObject, nodeName, conditions);
    return childNode.toString();
}
```

I'm confusing about if theses thread will be blocked? Because I thought if only a thread can invoke the static method?

Comment: where you are executing first code snippet (executors) inside call meyhod

Comment: Most likely this will lead to **terrible** performance. As each thread is loading new the JSON file anew. So not only are you repeating work, you are also going to cause hard disk thrashing. I don't know what library you are using, but if `JSONObject` is threadsafe you should load it once and reuse it, otherwise you need to rethink you approach entirely.

Comment: I create a test class to executing the first snippet

Comment: What is 'only a thread can invoke the static method' supposed to mean exactly? Only a thread can invoke *any* method.

Comment: Or, what EJP is trying to tell you is that threads _are_ what executes code.  Every statement that your program executes (including every method call) happens in _some_ thread.  When a program first starts up, its `main()` routine is called in the _main_ thread, which is no more special than any other thread.

Answer (score 0):

A method X can be invoked by multiple threads at the same time, except if it (or its class) is synchronized, in which case callers will be serialized timewise.

That said, just ensure that X be thread-safe.